# User limit for organizations

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am making a website with organizations. You can request to become part of an organizations. But the organizationshas to get a user limit of 500 people. it doesn't give an error and it won't go to my function either. Normally it just has to check if `current_users` is less then 500. And then the function has to update the user table and the organization.

**this is what I tried so far:**

```
<?php
 require '../conn.php';
 include '../session.php';
 $count = "SELECT `current_users` FROM `organisations` WHERE `org_id` = 
 '".$_POST['org']."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $count); // your query execution
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if($row['current_users'] < 500){
    $this->requestUserCreate()
} else {
    throw new Exception('Limit reached')
}

function requestUserCreate() {
$q = "UPDATE `organisations` SET `current_users` = `current_users` + 1 WHERE 
`org_id`='".$_POST['org']."'";
$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `active`= 1, `type` = 0 WHERE `user_id` = '" . 
$_POST['user'] . "'";
if ($conn->query($sql) && $conn->query($q) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}  
}
?>
```

this is my table for the organizations

```
CREATE TABLE `organisations` (
`org_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`path` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`type` int(1) NOT NULL,
`branche` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`niveau` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`current_users` int(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and this is for the users:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`user_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
`fnln` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`org_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`part_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`type` int(1) NOT NULL,
`active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

my javascript

```
function approveOne(user, org) {
swal({
    title: 'Are you sure to approve this users?',
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Approve user'
}).then(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "functions/save/approveUser.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {user, org},
        success: function (data) {
            swal(
                'Approved!',
                'You have approved the selected user.',
                'Success'
            );
            $("#newUsers").hide(250);
        },
        error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
}
```

and here is my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php include 'include/header.php'; ?>
<title>Student Concepts | Users</title>
</head>
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['type'])) {
if ($_SESSION['type'] != '1') {
    header('Location: index');
    die();
 }
}

function getUsers($orgID, $type)
{
require 'functions/conn.php';
$sql = "SELECT users.*, parts.* FROM users INNER JOIN parts ON users.part_id 
= parts.part_id WHERE users.org_id = '" . $orgID . "' AND users.active = '" 
. $type . "';";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<tr id="' . $row['user_id'] . '">';
        echo '  <td>' . $row['fnln'] . '</td>';
        echo '  <td>' . $row['username'] . '</td>';
        echo '  <td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
        echo '  <td>';
        if ($row['active'] == 0  || $row['active'] == 2) {
            echo '      <button class="button button-green" 
        onclick="approveOne('.$row['user_id'].', 
        '.$_SESSION['org_id'].')">Approve</button>';
        }
        echo '      <button class="button button-red" 
        onclick="deleteFromRelation(' . $row['user_id'] . 
        ');">Delete</button><br/>';
        echo '  </td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
}

?>
```

Comment: so getting errors???

Comment: @devpro no i don't get errors...

Comment: then what is the question??

Comment: @devpro why it doesn't work

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "does not work"? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase I changed my question. i hope now you understand

Comment: Have you checked what `$count` contains when you try to access it? I have a strong feeling that it contains a query and not the result from the database, so maybe you want to check for the return value of `mysqli_query`? Simple debugging would have helped you to spot that, and if you don't know how to do that it's the perfect day to learn it :) It will save you tons of grey hair

Comment: You might want to consider the use of a transaction so that if you've got two users wanting to join a group at the exact same moment, you eliminate the risk of them both being added to the group if there's only the room in the group for one of them

Comment: you need to use mysqli_num_rows here to get number of rows

Comment: @devpro this is what i have now

Comment: use `var_dump($row)` after this line `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` and share the result

Comment: your reply help be beneficial for future visitor

Comment: i tried but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the result of the query. Also, you have a logic error in the if `if ($count > 500)` should be `if ($count < 500)` because you want to add when you have less then 500

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $count);
if ($result !== false) {
    $totalRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($totalRows < 500) {
        $this->requestUserCreate();
    } else {
       throw new Exception('Limit reached');
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $count . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Now, an optimisation will be to remake the query, to use a  `count()`  function instead of  `select`

Comment: i tried what you said. it still doesn't work. i even changed my query to this `"SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE org_id = '".$_SESSION['org']."'";`

Comment: If you use count, then you have a different syntax: `SELECT COUNT(user_id) as total_rows FROM users WHERE ....` . Then you will parse the query result, something like `$totalRows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)['total_rows']`

Comment: Please keep in mind that stackoverflow is not a debugging service (something like: what is wrong with this complex function). Now, further in your code, if you want to insert something into a database, you use the `INSERT` statement, not `UPDATE`. Update is used for updating existing rows, insert for... inserting new rows. Start to debug your code, use var_dump or echo after each step and check if the values inside the variables are what you expect.